# Windows IoT Core Logs on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: logging, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I'v installed Windows IoT Core on my Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B) and successfully published some test .Net Core applications to it. Now i'm preparing a Background Application (i.e: Headless Application) and i want to write to the system's logs.

In the Raspberry's UI i see a section Explore > Logs, but it's totally empty. What logs does this section display and how do i get my application-specific logs to be listed there? How does this all work?

Answer (score 0):

Logs in the Explorer shows the logs which are auto-generated when the app crashes due to an unhandled exception. You can also manually generate a log by tapping on the command bar below and selecting "Quick-Save Log". The [IoTDefaultApp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/IoTCoreDefaultApp) is open source in GitHub, you can find the implement in this repo.

[image]
[image]

May i know if you know [Event Tracing for Windows IoT Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/eventtracing)? You can  make a custom event source to log for your application work on Windows 10 IoT Core.